Blazor server app using an AzureAdB2C for the authentication and running in Kubernetes
I have developed an Blazor server app that uses AzureAdB2C to authenticate users. The app is deployed in a kubernetes cluster and is accessible via a subdomain such as myapp.domain.com.
The authentication process works perfectly when there is only one pod running. However, when I increase the number of replicas for the workload, I encounter an HTTP 500 error after the authentication process (from Microsoft redirecting back to my app).
Here is the part of code for the authentication (located in Program.cs) :
builder.Services.AddAuthentication( options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated += OnTokenValidatedFunc;
    })
    ;

async Task OnTokenValidatedFunc(TokenValidatedContext context) {
    // Custom code here
    await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false); }

Could you please assist with this issue?

I am not sure if you are using ingress controller or not, if yes then enable sticky sessions (session affinity) in your ingress controller. Another solution is to use a distributed cache to store session state (such as user tokens) so that all pods share the same session data. You can use Redis or SQL Server as a distributed cache in aks

Since Blazor Server apps rely on server-side session state, and you're using multiple replicas in Kubernetes, you need to ensure that session state is not lost when requests are routed to different pods. As mentioned earlier, sticky sessions can help, but for better scalability and resilience, distributed session state management (like Redis) is the most reliable solution.
Create deployment and service to deploy the Blazor app and Redis.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: blazor-server-app
  labels:
    app: blazor-server-app
spec:
  replicas: 3 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: blazor-server-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: blazor-server-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: blazor-server-app
        image: arko/blazorapp:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: Redis__Configuration
          value: "myRedisCache.redis.cache.windows.net:6379"
        - name: Redis__InstanceName
          value: "BlazorAppInstance"
        - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
          value: "Production"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: blazor-server-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: blazor-server-app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80


FYI- If you don’t want to use Redis, then configure sticky sessions at the ingress level like this-
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: blazor-server-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myapp.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: blazor-server-service
              port:
                number: 80


Otherwise store session state in Redis, which ensures session data is available across all replicas.
In your program.cs of the Blazor Server app, configure Redis session state. Note, how you edit your program.cs depends on how you store your configuration values in the appsettings.json file.
If you store your Redis connection string under the ConnectionStrings section
then update it like this-
example-
builder.Services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisConnection");
    options.InstanceName = "MyAppInstance";
});

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

app.UseSession();


If you store Redis configuration under a custom section something like Redis__Configuration then -
builder.Services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = builder.Configuration["Redis__Configuration"];
    options.InstanceName = builder.Configuration["Redis__InstanceName"];
});

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    options.Events.OnTokenValidated += OnTokenValidatedFunc;
});

app.UseSession();


Ensure you have the proper Redis and Azure AD configuration in appsettings.json
Found few MS docs, check them once

Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with Azure Active Directory B2C
Secure a hosted ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly app with Azure Active Directory B2C

